# QML: Create cusom brush style based on standard Qt one

Tags: qml, qt5, brush, qbrush

I need custom brush style similar to `Qt.BDiagPattern` but with custom line width, let's say 10 or 20 px. Is there an easy way?

```
onPaint: {
    var ctx = getContext("2d");
    ...
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(Qt.rgba(1.0, 0, 0, 0.5),
                                      Qt.BDiagPattern);
    ctx.fill();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably have 2 options to create pattern - using a [color](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#createPattern-method) and using an [image](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#createPattern-method-1). in a html5 Canvas you have another option - [creating a pattern from another canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createPattern#creating_a_pattern_from_a_canvas) but looks that in the QML implementation this option is missing. So the only way is create a pattern from Image. If you really like complex solutions and you want some dynamic pattern you can create an Image using [QQuickImageProvider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html) and so use this image as a pattern.

Another option is using [CanvasImageData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvasimagedata.html)

```js
Canvas {
    id: patternCanvas
    anchors.fill: parent
    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext('2d');
        var pattern = ctx.createImageData(20, 20);

        for (let i = 0; i < pattern.data.length; i ++)
        {
              pattern.data[i] = Math.random() * 255;
        }

        ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(pattern, "repeat");
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,width, height);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

the data is array of bytes in RGBA format, i.e. every pixel is 4 array items.

Comment: Yes, creating `QQuickImageProvider` ancestor now.

Comment: Works, however writing algorithm for a smooth connectable fill pattern was tricky. Also why this image from [QQuickImageProvider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html) is not loaded in `ctx.createPattern(image, repeater)` method - nothing shown, need to load it in an `Image { source: image }` component first?

Comment: I don't know how did you try to load that but I guess that you have to create an Image somehow first since the `createPattern` wants Image as an argument

Comment: It wants Image or its URI. I pass URI for both `createPattern()` and arbitrary `Image{}` component. And 1st does not work without the 2nd for some reason. How would I pass created image?

Comment: Thanks for `CanvasImageData`, the code `BDiagPattern` similar pattern will be different. I already implemented the same in C++ with `QQuickImageProvider`, now need to figure out why it is not loaded with `createPattern()` if it was not loaded first with an `Image{}`.

Comment: This is why it was not loaded: [loadImage(url image)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-canvas.html#loadImage-method). **Note:** _Only loaded images can be painted on the Canvas item._ So I did this: `Canvas { Component.onCompleted: loadImage("uri") }`